# unemploymet analysis through social media

Tags: facebook, hadoop

unemployment analysis through social media in big data concept.In my application i need to retrieve a information of person from Facebook. Like the status of particular person and his degree,studies and current job of the person including previous job if he is not fresher. so which way to get this information. please tell me..

Then my output is like graphical representation. so i have to highlight each degree in the graph. the major objective is to produce the unemployment report.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achive is IMHO no longer possible with the Graph API >= v2.0. You'd need to get the permission of every user to get the data you want. You should have a look at the permission concept Facebook has implemented for its Graph API and see for yourself:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score -1):

First you need to use the Facebook Graph API to retrieve the available data for each user.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Then use a graphical library to draw what you want (but the question is a little too broad to go further).